# Иерархическая зависимость значений

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, как можно решить проблему:
Есть таблица `table1`:

```
Id      Group_id    Date        Val1    Val2
1       2           02.03.2018  9       4
2       1           02.03.2018  5       2
3       2           03.03.2018  6       1
4       1           02.03.2018  2       7
5       3           04.03.2018  3       6
6       1           05.03.2018  2       6
7       2           05.03.2018  3       5
8       3           04.03.2018  4       7
```

на базе которой триггерами заполняется табличка `table2`, в которой хранится расчетная, сгруппированная по group_id и отсортированная по датам (через параметр Seq, который обозначает порядковый номер в группе) информация:

```
Id      Group_id    Seq         Date            Summ
2       1           1           02.03.2018      1   
5       3           1           04.03.2018      2
1       2           1           02.03.2018      1
3       2           2           03.03.2018      3
4       1           2           02.03.2018      5
6       1           3           05.03.2018      7
7       2           3           05.03.2018      5
8       3           2           04.03.2018      3
```

Суть таких действий в том, что Summ в каждой группе имеет иерархическую зависимость, то есть зависит от значения в прошлой строке в этой группе.
Сама же проблема заключается в том, что пользователь имеет возможность вводить данные за рандомные даты и изменять у уже существующих записей group_id и Date. Как я представляю действия - если изменилась дата/group_id в table1, то такую запись нужно удалить в table2, пересчитать все послеидущие значения и вставить запись с новыми значениями, с нужным Seq и пересчитать все послеидущие значения. Но как это реализовать не понимаю. Или есть какие-то другие варианты решения?

Comment: А с какой целью была создана эта вторая таблица, почему требуемые значения не вычисляются всегда "на лету" по первой таблице ?

Comment: И если без этой таблицы все таки обойтись нельзя, то зачем в ней поле seq, даты вполне достаточно для любых запросов по этой таблице

Comment: При использовании оконных функций, на замену второй таблице, сильно проседает производительность, а seq нужно для того, что за одну дату может быть несколько записей.

Comment: стоп, т.е. записи в этой таблице вообще никак не сгруппированы и она фактически копия первой таблицы, только с проставленными кумулятивными значениями суммы ? А как тогда назначается seq в случае, если скажем в исходной таблице делается update даты в одной строке на '01.01.2018' и в этот момент в таблице2 уже существует 2 записи с такой же датой. Как решается что скажем запись ставится после них, а не в середину между ними ?

Comment: Для этого предполагал использовать `Id` из `table1`. То есть в таблице `table2` идентификатор не авто_инкримент, а `id` из `table1`. Если существую записи в `table2` за эту дату, ноимеют `id` 5 и 7, а изменили запись с `id` 6, то она вставится между ними.

Comment: Тогда seq точно не нужен. просто в запросах везде использовать `order by date, id`. тогда в триггере получаем значения из предыдущей строки, вставляем текущую с вычисленным значением (seq считать не нужно, что облегчает работу) после чего даем `update table2 set summ=summ+VAL where group_id=GROUP and date>=DATE and ( (date=DATE and id>ID) OR date>DATE )`. С удалением так же, только вычитаем значение текущей строки и после удаляем отрицательные или нулевые строки (если надо). На таблице разумеется должен быть индекс по `(group_id, date)`

Comment: Попробовал ваше решение, отлично решает мою задачу, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Наличие поля seq во второй таблице сильно усложняет логику, так как надо его постоянно пересчитывать. При том что в таблице есть другие поля, на основе которых порядок однозначно ясен. (По переписке в комментариях пришли к выводу что однозначный порядок задан полями date, id).

После того как уберем поле seq обновлять таблицу становится гораздо проще. При изменении записи по какой либо группе нам не надо пересчитывать вообще все кумулятивные значения по ней. Реально должны изменится лишь те значения, которые по датам/id идут позже изменяемой. Вычислять их значения с нуля опять же не надо, можно просто к всем записям после текущей добавить (или вычесть) дельту, на сколько они изменяются в результате операции.

Таким образом в триггере для добавляемой записи надо найти в table2 значение из предыдущей записи (`select summ from Table2 where group_id=NEW.group_id order by date desc, id desc limit 1`), сохранить текущую запись в table2 с значением текущей строки плюс полученная сумма. Добавить значение текущей строки ко всем последующим:

```
update table2
   set summ=summ+NEW.VAL
 where group_id=NEW.GROUP_ID and date>=NEW.DATE
   and ( (date=NEW.DATE and id>NEW.ID)
      OR date>NEW.DATE )
```

При удалении записи еще проще, удалить ее из Table2 после чего точно так же вычесть ее значение из всех последующих.